# Decrypt a 8 byte byte array in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, apdu

I'm using the below code to try to decrypt a 8 byte byte array..

```
public class AesGenericEncryptionService
{
    private readonly byte[] m_Key;
    private readonly byte[] m_IV;

    public AesGenericEncryptionService(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }
        else if (key.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iv));
        }
        else if (iv.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(iv));
        }

        m_Key = key;
        m_IV = iv;
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        }

        using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndaelManaged.KeySize = m_Key.Length * 8;
            rijndaelManaged.Key = m_Key;
            rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = m_IV.Length * 8;
            rijndaelManaged.IV = m_IV;

            using (var encryptor = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipher)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipher == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipher));
        }
        else if (cipher.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(cipher));
        }

        using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndaelManaged.KeySize = m_Key.Length * 8;
            rijndaelManaged.Key = m_Key;
            rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = m_IV.Length * 8;
            rijndaelManaged.IV = m_IV;

            using (var decryptor = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipher))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {

                var dycrypted = new byte[cipher.Length];
                var bytesRead = cryptoStream.Read(dycrypted, 0, cipher.Length);

                return dycrypted.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then try to run the code like so..

```
byte[] challenge = new byte[] { 0x93, 0x9d, 0x2c, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x65, 0x75, 0xd5 };


byte[] rndA = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };


byte[] defaultKey = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

var iv = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };


var crypto = new AesGenericEncryptionService(defaultKey,iv);

var decrypted= crypto.Decrypt(challenge);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(decrypted));
var str = BitConverter.ToString(decrypted).Replace("-", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.ReadLine();
```

which then fails on this line:

```
 rijndaelManaged.KeySize = m_Key.Length * 8;
```

with the error being:

```
Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.
```

I'm trying to convert this code from this article into c#:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mifare-desfire-introduction-david-coelho

Particularly this psudo code:

[image]

What am I doing wrong as I don't think I can change the size to a 16 byte array.. as what gets returned to me is a 8 byte array..

Comment: DES is not the same as Rijndael. They are completely different and incompatible, different algorithms, different key sizes, different block sizes, even different centuries. You should be using DES because that's what was used in the example.

Comment: One potential issue with the code is that the Decrypt method is not properly handling the case where the decrypted data is not the same length as the original cipher text. In the Decrypt method, the dycrypted byte array is initialized to the same length as the cipher text, but the cryptoStream.Read method may not read all of the data from the stream.

Comment: --cont This means that the returned array may contain uninitialized data at the end. To fix this issue, the dycrypted array should be initialized to a size equal to the number of bytes read from the stream, or the Take method should be used to only return the bytes that were read from the stream.